# Some Images are not Uniform and Proper

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I have tried to looked up in all the html source of theme. That theme is on a wordpress blog, but problem is when I use featured image on this ([url](https://pinoytvshows.mobi)) it is not all in same length. how can I make them stretched to fix in unifrom container? Can anyone tell me specific piece of code where I can fix this length?

I saw this line on functions.php in themes:

```
add_image_size('maggie-lite-featured-post', 2563, 480, true); //featured post img size
```

Comment: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_image_size/

Comment: Actually the problem is on home page with the image of that url I have mentioned above

Comment: There are many images on you home page can you send me screenshot .?